# How to put symbols '?' and '=' into url from variable?

Tags: php, url

In php I have function get_query_string() that returns me string variable. For example

```
$end_of_url = get_query_string();
print $end_of_url;
```

will print me

```
?id=192
```

I need to put this into the end of url, but when i append it, i have url like

http://mysite.com/device-information%3Fid%3D192

Question mark (?) is replaced in ascii value **%3F** and equal sign (=) in **%3D**.

How to put question mark and equal sign correctly into url?

**Code added:**

```
    <div id="navigationLang" class="clearfix" style="margin-right: 60px;"> 
            <?php 
                $path = $_GET['q'];
                $languages = language_list('enabled');
                $links = array();
                foreach ($languages[1] as $language) {
                    $links[$language->language] = array(
                        'href'       => $path.get_query_string(),
                        'title'      => ucfirst($language->prefix),
                        'language'   => $language,
                        'attributes' => array('class' => 'language-link'),
                    );
                }
```

---

```
function get_query_string(){
    $request_url = apache_getenv("HTTP_HOST") . apache_getenv("REQUEST_URI");
    $request_url = "http://".$request_url;
    $parts = parse_url($request_url);
    $end_of_url = $parts['query'];
    if ($end_of_url != "") {
        $end_of_url = '?'.$parts['query'];
        $a = htmlentities($end_of_url);
        $b = html_entity_decode($a);
        return $b;
    }
    else {return ""; }
}
```

Main problem is that print / echo works correctly, but when i test it in website links are with ascii symbols (%3F and %3D) and i need question mark and equal sign

Comment: use `htmlentities` or `htmlspecialchars`

Comment: It is url encoded. Show the code plz.

Answer (score 1):

That is because your `get_query_string()` is urlencoding.
Try:

```
print 'http://example.com/'.urldecode($end_of_url);
```

Comment: how do you exactly send to URL ?

Comment: what do you do with `$links` ?

Comment: print theme('links', $links, array());

Comment: this is too far ... you need to see what does the print of the URL, what is theme() now?

Comment: simply I print content when it is created. On my example, href is for icons that change website language. Href is the URL where it should go. It works fine, but when i have got something like ?id=192 and translate it, all after '?' disapears, so i need to get from previous url and add it to the end of link if there is something after question mark.

Comment: Everything works fine if i have no query string (something like ?id=192). But in translation i need full link (with ?id=192). Without function get_query_string() translation icon redirects only to http://mysite.com/en/device-information This is bad url because I have no ?id=192

Comment: I believe you, but one of your functiones is messing with the URL,

Comment: I tried many solutions and all had same problem :/
print / echo works perfect and i have correct string, but when i put into url with that 
href => $path.get_query_string() there are ascii symbols instead of '?' and '='

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by this:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];  // here i get id value (in example it's  192)

 $links[$language->language] = array(
                        'href'       => $path,
                        'title'      => ucfirst($language->prefix),
                        'language'   => $language,
                        'attributes' => array('class' => 'language-link'),
                        'query' => array('id' => $id),  // here i create end of url

                    );
```

Main point is that in drupal i should pass all stuff (?id=192) not in href, but add 'query' argument that is array. All question marks and equal signs added automatically, so i got right link with the end

```
?id=192
```

where 192 is variable from previous url.